# kendo ui for angular form components not working

Tags: user-interface, combobox, kendo-ui

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'forms',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  genders: Array<{text: string, value: number}> = [
     {text: 'Male', value: 1},
     {text: 'Female', value: 2},
     {text: 'Other', value: 3}
  ];
  
  myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
     firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     age: new FormControl(''),
     gender: new FormControl(1)
  });

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  onSubmit(value: string): void {
     console.log('submitted value is', value);
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Forms</h1>
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
   
   <label for="firstName" >First Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="first name" [formControl]="myForm.controls.firstName" />
   <span style="color: red">required</span>
   <br/>
   
   <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="last name" [formControl]="myForm.controls.lastName" />
   <span style="color: red">required</span>
   <br/>
   
   <label for="age">Age:</label>
   <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="age" [formControl]="myForm.controls.age" />
   <span style="color: red">required</span>
   <br/>
   
   <label for="gender">
      Gender:
      <kendo-combobox formControlName="gender" [data]="genders" [textField]="text" [valueField]="'value'" [valuePrimitive]="true" required></kendo-combobox>
   </label>
   
   
   <div *ngIf="!myForm.valid">Form is not valid</div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm trying to get the CombBox to work using Kendo UI for Angular.

I'm getting an error message saying that it kind bind to 'data' because it isn't a known property of 'kendo-combobox'.

below is a link from the telerik example I'm using.

Note that I'm using ReactiveForms

[Kendo UI for Angular ComboBox](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/forms/)

Comment: Show us your code, we can't guess the problem.

Comment: code is added in

Comment: What does your module definition look like? I've seen this problem when I wasn't properly importing the kendo libraries.

Comment: I figured it out this morning. And you are 100% correct. I wasn't correctly importing them. In the Telerik documentation at the forms section, it doesn't tell you that you need to install certain npm packages. But then by chance I moved on to dropdowns and saw everything I needed in that section to get it working.